# Question about the Diode

Tags: diodes

Turned on the diode means blocked current? or vise versa?
That made me confusing.
In here VCC and VEE is +12V, -12V. so, if Vin is 6V then upper OP amp will give +12V.  and below OP amp will give voltage -12V. then D1 will be not block and D2 will block. right? so..D1 is turn on? or off? How i have to call that?

[image]

Comment: You call it "forward-biased" or "conducting".

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you to reply me! Umm if forward-biased then turn on? or vise versa? I meant that

Comment: Forward-biased = conducting, reverse-biased = not conducting.

Comment: We tend to shy away from on/off for diodes, because **on** could imply that current could flow both directions. In a diode, current can ONLY flow in the forward direction. Hence, forward-bias or conducting are the preferred terms.

Comment: Thank you!~!! i got well.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGh0LR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a diode. If the anode is at a higher voltage than the cathode it will be forward biased and conducting or "on". The anode voltage has to be about 0.7V higher than the cathode, for a silicon diode, for it to conduct.

If the anode is at a lower voltage than the cathode it will be reverse biased, not conducting and off.

Comment: Hi, Regarding: "*The anode voltage has to be about 0.7V higher than the cathode, for a silicon diode, for it to conduct.*" As explained by @Andyaka in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/524917/101852), and as shown in figure 1 (If vs. Vf) in [this 1N4148 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds12019.pdf), the forward voltage drop can be significantly less than 0.7V at very low currents. Perhaps it's worth pointing out that 0.7V is more like a typical voltage drop for small diodes, at single-digit mA current & conduction can occur with <0.7V? Just a thought!

Comment: @SamGibson I absolutely agree with you and am very familiar with diode characteristic curves. However you have to be careful to apply the correct level of detail in a model to match the problem you are trying to answer. I was debating mentioning forward voltage drop at all.

Comment: Hi, I realised *you* would know this (from seeing your previous high-quality answers) and yes, perhaps not mentioning forward voltage drop at all would be better here. I just think *if* that topic is introduced, it's important to tell readers that diode Vf drop is more complicated than the classic "0.7V drop on a silicon diode" which we (or at least I) was taught in college. Otherwise people are surprised when they later find the places where that simplified statement *isn't* true!  Anyway, now we've had this exchange, I respect it's your choice to write your answer as you want. Thanks :-)

Comment: Really thank you!~!!